# SD card EROFS (read-only file system)

Tags: android, sd-card

We have customers who report that when our app tries to create and write a file on external SD card there is an I/O exception with EROFS (read-only file system).

The path seems it be correct : /storage/extSDCard/Android/data/com.myapp.mycompany/files/file.blah

This happens to just handful of customers.

Comment: have you defined write permission in Manifest file..??

Comment: `This happens to just handful of customers.` who use kitkat?

Comment: Not all KitKat customers. For majority it works just fine. It also works fine on our test KitKat devices

Comment: We have android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in our app manifest.

Comment: Have you finally found something interesting? I try to think some sdcards are just simply corrupted and will fail from time to time...

Comment: The permissions for a removable sdcard that is *secondary* to a built-in "external storage" have been odd on some past versions of Android, to the point where you may simply not be able to write there except by using a particular API.